# shell-mode `alias` keyword is not recognized as font-lock-builtin-face type

Tags: shell-mode, customize-face

In shell-mode; `alias` keyword is not recognized as `font-lock-builtin-face` type and remain as white color (with the current [theme](https://github.com/dracula/emacs) I am using it should be in different color)

=> Is it possible to add `alias` keyword into `font-lock-builtin-face` class?

---

This issue occurs in Ubuntu machine; with the same configuration it does not occur in a mac machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to your config should work the way you want, which BTW is the normal way to add font-lock keywords.

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode
  '(("alias" . font-lock-builtin-face)))
```