# How to color specific keywords in python-mode?

Tags: python, fonts

My goal is to color specific keywords as function definition such as `log` in `Python-mode` to a spefic color or color of functions.

Example, pattern for `log("....")`: coloring only `log`.

```
from utils import log  # no color for log
logging.info("hello")  # no color for log
log("hello world")  # color for log
```

I have tried follows answer for [shell-mode `alias` keyword is not recognized as font-lock-builtin-face type](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62032/18414) but it colors all the `log` string.

---

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'python-mode
                        '(("log" . font-lock-builtin-face)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this where you only apply the face to part of the match, in this case we mark log as group 1, and only apply the face to it. This pattern won't match the other places you show log above.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'python-mode
                        '(("\\(log\\)(.*)" 1 font-lock-builtin-face)))
```