# shell-mode how to color only keywords

Tags: shell-mode, customize-face

I have following definitions in my `.emacs` file for keyword coloring in `shell-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)

(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode '(("alias " . font-lock-builtin-face)))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode '(("mv " . font-lock-builtin-face)))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode '(("rm " . font-lock-builtin-face)))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode '(("cp " . font-lock-builtin-face)))
```

It successfully color those keywords but it also colors them if they are end of a word(string).

Example:

For `git clone https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm` it colors `rm` at the end:

[image]

Would it be possible to prevent this, where I just want to highlight the keyword?

Related: [shell-mode `alias` keyword is not recognized as font-lock-builtin-face type](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62032/18414)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`font-lock-add-keywords` takes a list of regular expressions, not merely strings. You can use the regular expression syntax to match more complicated constructs. In particular, you can match word boundaries with `\b`. Try this instead:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode '(("\\brm\\b" . font-lock-builtin-face)))
```

For more information on regular expressions, see [chapter 35.3.1.3 Backslash Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual. Don’t forget that you can open the manuals inside of Emacs using `C-h i`.

Also, just a head’s up; this function takes a list of multiple regexes. Instead of calling it four times, you can call it with one list of four things:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode '(("\\balias\\b" . font-lock-builtin-face)
                                      ("\\bmv\\b" . font-lock-builtin-face)
                                      ("\\brm\\b" . font-lock-builtin-face)
                                      ("\\bcp\\b" . font-lock-builtin-face)))
```

Because it takes regular expressions, you can also use alternations to express the same thing:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode '(("\\b\\(alias\\|mv\\|rm\\|cp\\|\\)\\b" . font-lock-builtin-face)))
```

Finally, there is a new syntax for regular expressions which is less traditional, but is often easier to read and maintain:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'shell-mode `((,(rx word-boundary
                                            (or "alias" "mv" "rm" "cp")
                                            word-boundary)
                                       . font-lock-builtin-face)))
```

This is documented in [chapter 34.3.3 The rx Structured Regexp Notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rx-Notation.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual.

Comment: For the last solution, I am getting following error: `Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 3013) signaled (invalid-function (rx word-boundary (or "alias" "unalias" "source"
"mkdir" "mv" "rm" "cp") word-boundary))` is it normal?

Comment: Oops, you’re right; I quoted it wrong! I will fix it.